# GitHub Actions: Error when copying generated directory to Docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, github, node-modules, github-actions

I am using GitHub Actions to build our [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) application.

These are some of the steps in the GitHub Actions workflow:

```
  - name: Build Nest application
    run: npm run build
  - run: ls -al
  - name: Build the Docker image
    run: docker build . --file github.Dockerfile
```

`github.Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM node:14-alpine as app
WORKDIR /usr/home/app
COPY package.json ./
COPY src ./
COPY node_modules ./
```

The build fails with this error message:

```
Step 5/5 : COPY node_modules ./
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder535687818/node_modules: no such file or directory
```

When listing the directory contents with `RUN ls -al`, this is the result:

```
drwxr-xr-x   9 runner docker   4096 Sep 29 12:53 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 runner docker   4096 Sep 29 12:52 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker   1541 Sep 29 12:52 .dockerignore
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker    663 Sep 29 12:52 .eslintrc.js
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker   1300 Sep 29 12:52 .gcloudignore
drwxr-xr-x   8 runner docker   4096 Sep 29 12:52 .git
drwxr-xr-x   3 runner docker   4096 Sep 29 12:52 .github
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker    388 Sep 29 12:52 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker     51 Sep 29 12:52 .prettierrc
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker   3370 Sep 29 12:52 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker    162 Sep 29 12:52 cloudbuild.yaml
drwxr-xr-x   2 runner docker   4096 Sep 29 12:53 dist
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker    102 Sep 29 12:52 github.Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x   2 runner docker   4096 Sep 29 12:52 k8s
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker     64 Sep 29 12:52 nest-cli.json
drwxr-xr-x 134 runner docker   4096 Sep 29 12:53 node_modules
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker 521420 Sep 29 12:52 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker   1923 Sep 29 12:52 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker    471 Sep 29 12:52 skaffold.Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker    446 Sep 29 12:52 skaffold.yaml
drwxr-xr-x   2 runner docker   4096 Sep 29 12:52 src
drwxr-xr-x   2 runner docker   4096 Sep 29 12:52 test
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker     97 Sep 29 12:52 tsconfig.build.json
-rw-r--r--   1 runner docker    339 Sep 29 12:52 tsconfig.json
```

`package.json` and `src` are part of the Git repository. `node_modules` gets generated in the process of the GitHub Action.

Why can't `node_modules` be copied to the Docker container, while both `package.json` and `src` can?

Comment: `docker build` `[OPTIONS]` should be set before the context (i.e. `docker build --file github.Dockerfile .`). The `docker build` syntax is: [`docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -`.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#usage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out `node_modules` was included in the `.dockerignore` file. ‍♂️

Comment: You have no idea how much I appreciate this post, 3 hours of my life that I'll never get back... but so we learn!